# DataFrame Floats to Ints?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to programming and I have written a program that reads and modifies a large excel file using Python Pandas. In the code I have the following line:

```
df1 = df1.apply(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x,errors='ignore'))
```

Which does what I need it to, but it also turns the data below my header into floats. Is there a way to have them turn to and int type instead?

df1 is a dataframe and I am attempting to create a nested dictionary with its contents.

Comment: A general tip, look in the docs for params: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html. Also look at dtype when using read_excel.

Comment: `df['column'].astype('int')` not working?

Comment: note also that if you have missing values then pandas converts to float b/c float is the only numeric type in pandas that supports missing values (NaN)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 2**

Use this for a list of numeric columns in an existing dataframe:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df1[cols] = df1[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore', downcast='integer')
```

The standard `astype(int)` is sub-optimal since it doesn't downcast by default.

**Option 1**

As @AntonvBR mentions, ideally you want to *read in* series as downcasted integers, if at all possible. Then this separate conversion would not be necessary.

For example, the `dtype` parameter of `pd.read_excel` takes a dictionary input:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', dtype={'Col1': np.int8})
```

This will only work if you know your columns in advance.

Comment: If he/she knows in beforehand which columns that should be applied using dtype would be way more efficient.

Comment: It's just if you read between the lines OP is reading a large excel file. In any other case downcast integer is the way.